# Java Generics Interface and Spring GetBean by Id and Class type

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a generic interface to which I can provide many implementation, For each such implementation I am associating a id attribute in the spring definition file.

```
IConfigurationService<T>
```

Now I am trying to write a utility method which can fetch me implementation by id.

Following method is a utility method which throws me a warning message:

```
public <T extends Serializable> IConfigurationService<T> getBean(Class<T> type, String id){
        return (IConfigurationService<T>)context.getBean(id, IConfigurationService.class);
    }
```

Warning message:
Type safety: Unchecked cast from IConfigurationService to IConfigurationService.

How do I get rid of the this warning message?

If I change the return statement as follows, then I am getting compilation error:

```
return (IConfigurationService<T>)context.getBean(id, IConfigurationService<T>.class);
```

I would be helpful if I someone can identify what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get rid of that warning other than supressing it. This is because of the runtime type erasure in Java generics. The class literal `IConfigurationService.class` doesn't provide any generic type information. So you get a `IConfigurationService<?>` returned from `context.getBean`. You have to cast that to the appropriate type.

But you might use a workaround for that. When you declare

```
@Resource
private IConfigrationService<Foo> configService;
```

in one of your spring context managed classes, then spring will make sure to only inject an implementation of `IConfigurationService` whose type parameter is compatible with `Foo`.

Comment: Since I am writing a utility method, @Resource annotation doesn't help me, as in my utility method can return IConfigrationService<Foo> and IConfigrationService<Bar>

Comment: just a thought, if spring can autowire it without the typecasting issue, I should be able do it too..

Comment: @Chetan You could at least use `java.lang.Class.getTypeParameters()` and verify that against the `type` parameter of your method. Have a look at gentyref for accomplishing that - http://code.google.com/p/gentyref/

Answer (score -1):

So you have one interface which has many implementations right? Why not use @Qualifier for each of the implementations and use the qualifier when injecting the implementation with @Resource?

Comment: There is a reason for not using them in my requirement. So solution this particular problem statement would be really helpful.